# Gather Table stats vs Compute stats

Tags: oracle

Can any one please let me know the difference between, and what exactly it 
will do in backend.

`DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` and `analyze table compute statistics` and 
estimate statistics.

I have googled for it but didn't find correct answer till now.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `analyze table` is deprecated for gathering statistics for the cost based optimizer.

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4005.htm#BABHEEDA) there are only two things for which `analyze` should be used:

- To use the VALIDATE or LIST CHAINED ROWS clauses
- To collect information on freelist blocks

To gather statistics for the optimizer, use `dbms_stats`.

The manual also describes what the `dbms_stats` package does:

> For the collection of most statistics, use the DBMS_STATS package, **which lets you collect statistics in parallel, collect global statistics for partitioned objects, and fine tune your statistics collection in other ways**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In addition, when using dbms_stats(), use AUTO sample size; do not try and specify a percentage.